# Can svg clip-path property be used on tspan element

Tags: dom, text, svg

Even after a lot of search I can't find any mention of this over the net. And When I tried to use clip-path on a tspan element, it didn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong or clip-path doesn't work for tspan elements that are nested inside a text element?
This is my svg code I am trying.

```
 <svg width="500px" height="500px">
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath841">
    <rect width="10" y="0" x="0" height="100%"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <text y="130" x="125"  __internalID="internal281">
    <tspan textLength="30" clip-path="url(#clipPath841)">
Hello world how are you what are you doing
</tspan>
    </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, the height and width are just there when I was experimenting with it. What I don't get is the clip-path seems to work just fine when used with regular text elements, not with tspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [SVG 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath) you cannot set a clipPath on a tspan.

> Applies to:   container elements, graphics elements and ‘clipPath’

And [tspan is not a graphics element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement).

The upcoming SVG 2 specification may change this.